# inserting mathjax equation into innerHTML from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to put a MathJax equation into the innerHTML element.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Tools for Operation Research</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:/_Installers/MathJax-2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="main_content">
            Put text here:
        </section>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("main_content").innerHTML = "The expresion is: <br> $$\displaystyle Q^*=\sqrt{\left( \frac{2DA}{h}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{D}{\psi}}\right)\left(\frac{h+\pi}{\pi}\right)}$$";
        </script>
    </body>
```

The result is this:

$$displaystyle Q^*=sqrt{left( rac{2DA}{h} ight)left(rac{1}{1-rac{D}{psi}} ight)left(rac{h+pi}{pi} ight)}$$

not the equation.
Shoulb be something like this:
[Correct equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CGJt.png)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript Compiler unescapes backslash escaping

Because JavaScript uses backslash escaping, all the `'\'` characters before unrecognized letters in the equation are being removed by the JavaScript compiler, and `'\r'` is turned into an ASCII carriage return character which HTML then displays as whitespace.

The solution is to backslash escape the backslashes in the equation:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("main_content").innerHTML = "The expresion is: <br> $$\\displaystyle Q^*=\\sqrt{\\left( \\frac{2DA}{h}\\right)\\left(\\frac{1}{1-\\frac{D}{\\psi}}\\right)\\left(\frac{h+\pi}{\\pi}\\right)}$$";
</script>
```

Note I was able to verify the equation was displayed as symbols using  a downloaded copy of MathJax from a CDN, but did not attempt a local installation.